# Compute $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{ikt}}{|e^{it}-e^{it_0}|^m}~\text{d}t$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $t_0\in\mathbb{C}$, and $m=1,3,5,\dots$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-series, contour-integration, branch-points

I want to compute

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}kt}}{\,\left\vert\,{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t} - {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t_{0}}}\,\,\right\vert^{\, m}\,}\,{\rm d}t,
$$

where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $t_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$, and $m = 1,3,5,\ldots$. The integrand experiences a singularity at
$t=t_0$ and $t = \bar{t}_{0}$. We may assume that
$\left\vert{\,{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t_{0}}\,}\right\vert < 1$. However, if someone is able to make any progress for any $m$ and e.g. for only $k > 0$, it would be of much help.

---

You may also consider the integral rewritten into a contour integral over the unit circle $S$ by letting $\xi\left(t\right)={\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}$ and $\mu = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t_0}$,

$$
\frac{1}{i}\oint_{S}\frac{\xi^{k - 1}}{\left\vert\xi-\mu\right\vert^{m}}\,{\rm d}\xi.
$$

Another reformulation is to let $t_{0} = a_{0}+ {\rm i}b_{0}$ and $\alpha = {\rm e}^{-b_{0}}$. Then, the integral can be found as

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\frac{\cos\left(kt\right) + {\rm i}\sin\left(kt\right)}
{\,\left\{\left(1 + \alpha\right)^{2} -
2\alpha\left[1 - \cos\left(t - a_{0}\right)\right]\right\}^{m/2}\,}~\text{d}t,$$

where one may treat the two integrals separately.

I have not been able to make any significant progress on any of these three formulations.

Comment: If it wasn't for absolute value in the denominator, you could use Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @Esgeriath Exactly, the absolute value makes this integral tricky. It would also be easier if $m=2,4,6,\dots$, but that is not the case I am interested in.

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Precise evaluation of integrals of a modulus is tricky in the complex plane as all holomorphic function theory goes out the window

Comment: in what sense do you want an answer; for example for $m=1, k=0$ and say $e^{it_0}=b$ real in $(-1,1)$ the integral is more or less a complete elliptical integral of the first kind in a parameter related to $b$ (and same is true when $e^{it_0}$ is not real but it is more complicated to express the parameter), while for say $k=1$ is a combination of elliptical integrals of first and second kinds; same for other $m,k$ but it gets more and more complicated of course

Comment: @Conrad The answer I would like is a closed-form expression of the integral for a specific value of $m$ (e.g. $m=1$) in terms of $k$ that is relatively cheap to evaluate. Typical value of $k$ that I would want to evaluate the integral for would be $|k|<N$, where $N\approx 10^2$.

Comment: @FShrike I am working on a quadrature method where this integral, which can be viewed as quadrature weights, appears. And actually, it originates from a line integral in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that does not show.

Comment: The closed value is going to be in terms of elliptic integrals (which are hypergeometric series and have been studied for 2 centuries so there may be what you need in the vast literature) with computable coefficients (quadratic and quartic roots to start with as they come from transforming $\sqrt {a+b\sin t+c\cos t} $ into $d\sqrt {1-m^2\sin^2 (t +\psi)}$) and then various integration by parts and the like; so I would suggest focusing on one specific case and working it out to see if it gives you what you want